# Passing variables to email footer in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email

I would like to show a disclaimer in the footer saying

> This email was sent to {recipients email address}.

but i can't figure out how i can get the email address into the standard footer blade.

Here is what I have:
In my notification component I make the following call with $rcp_email having the email address of the recipient:

```
return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Contact Form Submitted')
            ->markdown('emails.generic.contactform', [
                'first_name' => $this->first_name,
                'message' => $this->message,
                'rcp_email' => $this->rcp_email,
                'url_security_issue' => $url_security_issue,
            ]);
```

The emails.generic.contactform looks like this

```
@extends('emails.main')
@section('content')
(body of email)
@endsection
```

emails.main looks like this

```
@component('mail::message')
@yield('content')
@if (isset($unsubscribe_url))
(html code for unsubscribe)
@endif
@endcomponent
```

the standard vendor\mail\html\message blade looks like this:

```
@component('mail::layout')
{{-- Header --}}
@slot('header')
@component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.front_end_url'), 'logo' => asset('logo-image-white-circular-background.png')])
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
@endslot
{{-- Body --}}
{{ $slot }}

{{-- Subcopy --}}
@isset($subcopy)
@slot('subcopy')
@component('mail::subcopy')
{{ $subcopy }}
@endcomponent
@endslot
@endisset

{{-- Footer --}}
@slot('footer')
@component('mail::footer')
 © {{ date('Y') }} {{ config('app.name') }}. @lang('All rights reserved.')
@endcomponent
@endslot
@endcomponent
```

I traced each level of blade and $rcp_email is first of all not availble in the message blade. I tried to pass it on by changing the first line of emails.main to

```
@component('mail::message', ['rcp_email' => $rcp_email])
```

but in either case when i try to use the variable in the message blade, i get the error Undefined variable: rcp_email

In an ideal case, I would want to add the html code and make use of the variable in the actual footer blade, but I don't know if that's possible.

I would much appreciate if there is any hints/any docus or articles you can share that describes in depth how this works?

Thanks,
Goppi

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

hopefully this helps for others with issue
From what I did, when you use `@component('mail::message', ['rcp_email' => $rcp_email])` it will pass the variable `$rcp_email` to the message blade.

Here change your message blade `@component('mail::footer')` to `@component('mail::footer', ['rcp_email' => $rcp_email])` to pass it again to your footer blade.

In footer blade access the variable like `{{$rcp_email}}`
so example would be `<p>sent to {{$rcp_email}}</p>`

Also as a note, when passing the variable like `['name' => $variable]` it uses the name as the variable in the next blade. so here you would access it like `$name`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Jack C - your solution didn't work for me back then as you can see from my original post. I tried to pass rcp_email on to the message blade using

```
@component('mail::message', ['rcp_email' => $rcp_email])
```

and when I tested $rcp_email within the message blade, it came back with undefined variable. That said, I didn't figure out why it wasn't working, but I used @component with variables for other blades without issues. Perhaps it didn't work due to caching issue.

The solution that I came up with back then opened itself up once I decided not to use the standard email template, but design my own.
The emails.generic.contactform changed as follows:

```
@extends('emails.layout.layout')
@section('content')
{{-- body of email --}}
@endsection
```

The emails.layout.layout blade looks like this:

```
@component('mail::layout')
{{-- Content --}}
{{-- Footer --}}
@slot('footer')
@component('mail::footer')
{{ $recipient ?? '' }}
@endcomponent
@endslot
```

to summarize, my understanding on how to pass variables between blades is as follows:

1. extend - extends allows the layout blade to use all variables with the same names as the extended blade.

   ```
   @extends('layout')
   ```
2. components have no access to the variables of the parent blade. Instead they need to be passed on. There are two ways to pass them on: as one or more variables or as a slot. In the example below $name is available within the component footer.

   ```
   @component('footer', ['name' => $rcp_email])
   @endcomponent
   ```
3. component - the second way is as a slot. In the example below the variable $slot would contain the email address.

   ```
   @component('footer')
   {{ $rcp_email }}
   @endcomponent
   ```